# When creating a customizable value with defcustom, how can I validate users' entries?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm writing an elisp file that's evolving into a package, so I'm translating some of its variables into `defcustom` statements and documenting them. A few of these `defcustom` variables are related, and I'd like to validate values entered through the Customize system to ensure that the relationships hold true.

Here's an example of what I have:

```lisp
(defcustom widget-canonical-names '("my_widget" . "widget_assembly 8911_j4")
  "Documentation"
  :type '(alist :key-type (string :tag "Widget's short name")
                :value-type (string :tag "Full widget name"))
  :risky nil
  :group 'widgets)
(defcustom widget-colors '("my_widget" . "brown")
  "Documentation"
  :type '(alist :key-type (string :tag "Widget's short name")
                :value-type (color :tag "color of the widget"))
  :risky nil
  :group 'widgets)
(defcustom widget-paths '("my_widget" . "~/widgets")
  "Documentation"
  :type '(alist :key-type (string :tag "Widget's short name")
                :value-type (directory :tag "support files for widget"))
  :risky nil
  :group 'widgets)
```

So there are widgets and they have various settings, and I need to be able to access an arbitrary setting for a widget by knowing just the widget's short name. I'd like to make a validation function of some kind (googling around for "emacs defcustom validate" hasn't helped, unfortunately) such that if the user enters a widget name in `widget-paths` or `widget-colors` that is not in the `widget-canonical-names` list, they get an "are you sure?" warning and are cautioned about entering mismatched names. Can I attach such a validation function to my `defcustom`s? If so, what's the syntax for that?

Of course, what would be ideal would be to just make the user enter the short name once, but I can't figure out how to do that from the 'Composite Types' elisp documentation. So an even better answer to my question would tell me how to arrange a `defcustom` that sets up a data structure similar to this Python dict:

```python
customized_widgets = {
    "my_widget": { "canonical_name": "widget_assembly 8911_j4",
                   "widget_color": "brown",
                   "widget_path": "~/widgets",
                 },
    "another_widget": { "canonical_name" : "widget_obsolete 11.0",
                        "widget_color": "blue",
                        "widget_path": "~/blue_widgets",
                      },
     }
```

So: how can I get the behavior I want, where settings are grouped according to the data that'll be used to access them, or where a validation function warns users when they might be entering inconsistent data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will define the closest Emacs equivalent of that Python structure, with dicts represented as alists, and fixed keys of the inner dict represented as symbols.

```
(defcustom my-customized-widgets ()
  "My widget customization alist"
  :type '(alist
          :tag "Widgets"
          :key-type (string :tag "Short name")
          :value-type
          (set
           :format "%v"
           :entry-format "%b %v"
           (cons :format "%v"
                 (const :format "" widget-canonical-name)
                 (string :tag "CName"))
           (cons :format "%v"
                 (const :format "" widget-color)
                 (color :tag "Color"))
           (cons :format "%v"
                 (const :format "" widget-path)
                 (directory :tag " Path"))))
  :group 'widgets)
```

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem. :) In case it's not obvious, it addresses the "what would be ideal would be to just make the user enter the short name once" variant.

Comment: I was waiting to accept it 'til I'd tried it in context, which I now have. Also it helped some of the Customize documentation make sense to me. Thanks. :)

Comment: Hmmm. Life is full of challenges: that gives me the data structure I need at the cost of looking very ugly in Customize. I'd better keep working.

Comment: Customize is often like that. :) There are many options for creating widgets, and the documentation is quite sparse. I edited the answer to make it a bit more appealing, at least to me - see if you like it.

Comment: Oh hey, that's what I'm after! Thank you very much: I was *way* out in the wild and unfamiliar territory of Customize's `:get` and `:set` trying to get it to look like that. I guess I can let this savage lambda back into the wild now.

Comment: I noticed another problem with my code: it required the canonical-name, color, and path to be exactly in that order, which is not in spirit of your Python subdict, which is orderless. This will still works if the values are only added through customize, but if someone adds a value manually in the wrong order, customize won't recognize it. I've now edited it to use `set`, which isn't picky about the order, but allows leaving some items out with a checkbox, which I can't find a way to remove. Other than the checkbox, it looks very similar to the last version.